# order by after grouping in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb

How to order after grouping in Rethinkdb  like in sql:

```
select count(id) as cid, ... from x 
group by y
order by cid desc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I properly understood your question, the query you are looking for is (in JavaScript)

```
 r.table("x").group("y").count().ungroup().orderBy("reduction")
```

In Python/Ruby, it would be

```
 r.table("x").group("y").count().ungroup().order_by("reduction")
```